# cppcheck can't find include files

Tags: c++, cppcheck

cppcheck can't find even standard headers such as iostream. Any ideas?

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and cppcheck from the repository.

Comment: Check if they are installed...

Comment: @tyz: I think the idea is that cppcheck knows about ANSI/C++ w/o any headers. So I think it won't even understand gcc specific system headers etc..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

cppcheck is really bad at finding standard include headers, on Mac and Linux. Fortunately, you can suppress this check, and only scan your custom header files:

```
cppcheck --enable=all --suppress=missingIncludeSystem .
```

Comment: This supress-flag gives me the following error: `Unmatched suppression: missingIncludeSystem`... Or does this simply mean that the check didn't suppress any arror? Can I suppress the non-suppressed suppress-error then? O:)

Comment: Yes, you can suppress the 'unmatched suppression' error, with --suppress=unmatchedSuppression. :)

Comment: Judging by the man page,I think this is named `missingInclude` now.

Answer (score 26):

It isn’t recommended to provide the paths to the standard C/C++
headers - Cppcheck has internal knowledge about ANSI C/C++ and it
isn’t recommended that this known functionality is redefined. But feel
free to try it.

```
-I [dir]
```

Give include path. Give several -I parameters to give several paths.
First given path is checked first. If paths are relative to source
files, this is not needed.

Comment: The `-I` option can make `cppcheck` run very slowly if you bring in a lot of headers.

Comment: And don't get it mixed up with the '-i' (ignore) option.

Comment: I think this is a better answer, at least for me, my headers are not in to project root directory. So if suppressing the warning no headers will be checked.