# Bringing Cppcheck and VCL together

Tags: properties, vcl, cppcheck, temporary-objects, false-positive

Cppcheck now has a check to detect references to temporary which leads to false positives (`danglingTemporaryLifetime`) for code involving VCL classes (of C++Builder6).

Here is `test.cpp`

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <string>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:
    TButton *Button1;
public:
    explicit __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TTest
{
public:
    std::string GetText() const;
    void Init()
    {
        m_form->Caption = GetText().c_str();
        m_form->Button1->Caption = "Text";
    }
    TForm1* m_form;

    // Forbidden:
    TTest(const TTest&);
    TTest& operator=(const TTest&);

};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

an example that compiles in BCB6 and, if invoked like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe" --enable=style --inconclusive test.cpp
```

reproduces the error:

```
Checking test.cpp ...
test.cpp:23:9: error: Using pointer to temporary. [danglingTemporaryLifetime]
        m_form->Button1->Caption = "Text";
        ^
test.cpp:22:34: note: Pointer to container is created here.
        m_form->Caption = GetText().c_str();
                                 ^
test.cpp:23:9: note: Using pointer to temporary.
        m_form->Button1->Caption = "Text";
        ^
```

I [learned that one should not provide the include path to the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6986088/2932052) and never tried to do it for the VCL either. But now Cppcheck doesn't cope with the `Caption` property of a class that's not known. The error is given for the next member access (that to `Button1` which is known) and the unknown member with the temporary assigned to it still has an effect here.

I also tried to tell the VCL include path to Cppcheck by adding

```
 -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\Vcl"
```

But this leads to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\Vcl\sysvari.h:3365:0: error: No pair for character ("). Can't process file. File is either invalid or unicode, which
is currently not supported. [preprocessorErrorDirective]
#pragma message "ERROR: sizeof(TVarData) < sizeof(VARIANT)'
^
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `__property` is a non-standard extension in the Borland/Embarcadero C++ compilers. There are quite a few semantics related to `__property`, so unless you can alter CppCheck's source code, or create a custom addon, to handle those semantics, it is not likely you are going to be able to make it handle properties correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Cppcheck has a bit of handling of such class properties. I don't want Cppcheck to write garbage for your code.

Can you show me how to reproduce? I have put your code in a file 1.cpp and with the command `cppcheck --enable=style --inconclusive 1.cpp` I get no warning.